# MySQL Update column based on another table using a trigger

Tags: mysql

I currently have this mySQL code...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_ChairData_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON ChairData
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM ProductionTimes as PT;
UPDATE ChairData SET Labour=`PT.Cut`+`PT.Sew`+`PT.UPH`+`PT.QC/Pack`;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

...but I get this error in phyMyAdmin...

## #1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

I have never used triggers before so I am uncertain how to properly do this.

Comment: Use `Select Into` to get results from your select query stored into a variable. And, then use those variables in the update query

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

There are lots of other issues in your trigger; without making use of `NEW` and `OLD`, it does not seem to serve any purpose here.

Comment: Quite simply trying to get the `Labour` column in the table `ProductionTimes` to be automatically updated as the sum of `Cut`, `Sew`,`UPH` and `QC/Pack` from the `ChairDarta` table.  The trigger seemed to be the best approach but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: What is the join relationship between the ChairDarta table and ProductionTimes table. Currently your update query will update the value for **all the rows**. I doubt that you want to update all the rows.

Comment: Again... I am very new to this so please have patience with me. There is currently no relationship between the tables. I am trying to establish that here. I need the `Labour` column in the table `ProductionTimes` to be automatically updated as the sum of `Cut`, `Sew`,`UPH` and `QC/Pac`k from the `ChairDarta` table. The trigger seemed to be the best approach but I maybe not. Looking at it now I think the trigger should be `AFTER` update on `ProductionTimes` but I still have no idea what the rest of the code should be.

Comment: No worries, take your time! Currently, your requirement is bit unclear. I would suggest you some reading on Triggers, and especially read about `NEW` and `OLD` keywords in Triggers. Refer this nice tutorial here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx

Comment: Also, please post a minimal sample data for the two tables concerned here, and expected output at the end of the trigger's successful run. Please refer this link on how to frame a sample data: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333953/2469308

Comment: Add the output from `show create table ProductionTimes; show create table ChairData;`.

Comment: The below answer shows the results from your input!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the comments about and a few Google searches to expand on it, I came up with this solution...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_ProductionTimes_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON ProductionTimes
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

UPDATE ChairData SET Labour=NEW.Cut+New.Sew+NEW.UPH+NEW.`QC/Pack` WHERE `Style`=NEW.Style;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What I was unaware of is that you can use NEW to refer to the value from the record that was just updated. No need to try and "SELECT" from the database... just update the other table.

Comment: Now as I look at your solution, it seems that you can better approach this using Generated/Calculated columns instead. If your MySQL server version >= 5.7; you can use them instead. Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html  
and  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/